# select DISTINCT but dont mess with the order of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

If you want to play with my data I have added a playground to the very end of the post. Thank you.

SCHEMA

```sql
CREATE TABLE "public"."posts" (
    "id" bigint NOT NULL,
    "text" "text",
    "user_id" "uuid" NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO "public"."posts" ("id", "text", "user_id" ) VALUES (173, 'iOS created', '9361a62b-462a-4ca3-ba1d-e0c2e0174aa0');
INSERT INTO "public"."posts" ("id", "text", "user_id" ) VALUES (174, 'chrome reply', '90a42a87-9f9b-4676-bc6a-214be0050053');
INSERT INTO "public"."posts" ("id", "text", "user_id" ) VALUES (175, 'brave reply', '00bf9dae-e5a7-4f86-a3fd-0be4630cffd4');
INSERT INTO "public"."posts" ("id", "text", "user_id" ) VALUES (176, '@1 chrome mention', '9361a62b-462a-4ca3-ba1d-e0c2e0174aa0');
INSERT INTO "public"."posts" ("id", "text", "user_id" ) VALUES (177, '@0 ios mention', '00bf9dae-e5a7-4f86-a3fd-0be4630cffd4');
INSERT INTO "public"."posts" ("id", "text", "user_id" ) VALUES (178, '', '00bf9dae-e5a7-4f86-a3fd-0be4630cffd4');
INSERT INTO "public"."posts" ("id", "text", "user_id" ) VALUES (179, '@2 mention brave', '9361a62b-462a-4ca3-ba1d-e0c2e0174aa0');
```

QUERY

```sql
select * from
(
  select 
  --DISTINCT ON (user_id)
  text,
  row_number() over() rank,
  user_id
  from
  (
    SELECT 
    id,
    text,
    user_id
    FROM posts
    order by id asc
  ) alias1
) alias2
```

Does what i want, but I want to GROUP BY `user_id` and keep the lowest `rank` possible. When using `DISTINCT (user_id) *` the `rank` is taken by what feels random, that is the issue.

Uncomment `--DISTINCT ON (user_id)` on the playground to see `rank` take random rows instead of taking the first `rank`ings rows.

Output without `DISTINCT`

```
rank    user_id text
1   9361a62b-462a-4ca3-ba1d-e0c2e0174aa0    iOS created
2   90a42a87-9f9b-4676-bc6a-214be0050053    chrome reply
3   00bf9dae-e5a7-4f86-a3fd-0be4630cffd4    brave reply
4   9361a62b-462a-4ca3-ba1d-e0c2e0174aa0    @1 chrome mention
5   00bf9dae-e5a7-4f86-a3fd-0be4630cffd4    @0 ios mention
6   00bf9dae-e5a7-4f86-a3fd-0be4630cffd4    
7   9361a62b-462a-4ca3-ba1d-e0c2e0174aa0    @2 mention brave
```

Output with `DISTINCT`

```
rank    user_id text
5   00bf9dae-e5a7-4f86-a3fd-0be4630cffd4    @0 ios mention
2   90a42a87-9f9b-4676-bc6a-214be0050053    chrome reply
4   9361a62b-462a-4ca3-ba1d-e0c2e0174aa0    @1 chrome mention
```

Output i need:

```
rank    user_id text
1   9361a62b-462a-4ca3-ba1d-e0c2e0174aa0    iOS created
2   90a42a87-9f9b-4676-bc6a-214be0050053    chrome reply
3   00bf9dae-e5a7-4f86-a3fd-0be4630cffd4    brave reply
```

Query with my data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/df83a/2/0

Comment: The `order by` in your sub-query is irelevant and you are not applying row numbers in any specific order, so yes you are going to get inconsistent results - I don't know Postgres well but row_number in most RDBMS cannot be used with `over()`

Comment: @Stu row_number needs an over() as when I remove that and run the query (which you can too in the playground URL provided) it tells me to add it.

Comment: @Stu but either way, the query itself works fine. I just need a parent query to get my desired output. Does not matter how it's done.

Comment: Providing a fiddle is nice but the [example] needs to be on site completely. If the fiddle gets down, the question is still useful that way. So [edit] the question and include the code from the fiddle as well.

Comment: @stickybit the whole code is there, its one query with a conditional comment :)

Comment: Here are no `CREATE` or `INSERT` statements to create the environment.

Comment: @stickybit fair enough, added

Comment: I think you need to explain your ranking criteria, your query does not rank anything.

Comment: @Stu ive tried many things, but i cannot get to the desired output. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables, views, query results, etc. in relational databases represent relations. Relations are a special form of (multi) sets. Sets don't have an order. So the DBMS is free to deliver a result of a query in *any* order it "wants" *unless* there's an explicit `ORDER BY`. That's why you get "random" results.

So use proper `ORDER BY` clauses for `DISTINCT ON` and `row_number()`. Use an outer query with an `ORDER BY` to order the end result.

```
SELECT rank,
       user_id,
       text
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
                    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rank,
                    user_id,
                    text
                    FROM posts
                    ORDER BY user_id,
                             id) AS x
       ORDER BY rank;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8cd5132b45e8d3baef54ff72f96977e1)

Comment: thank you, exactly what i was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery with a group by:

```
select posts.* from posts
inner join
(
  select 
  user_id, min(id) as minId
  from posts
  group by user_id
) p on p.user_id = posts.user_id and p.minId = posts.Id;
```

EDIT: To have something that you call 'rank' but is a row_number really:

```
select row_number() over (order by posts.id) as rank, 
   posts.user_id, posts.text from posts
inner join
(
  select 
  user_id, min(id) as minId
  from posts
  group by user_id
) p on p.user_id = posts.user_id and p.minId = posts.Id;
```

Comment: Thank you, using your method I'd need to use another LEFT JOIN to get my `rank` into the output, hence why i choose the selected answer over yours. Still appreciate your post!

Comment: @sdjkhduiueeuzie, would you explain why would you need to use a LEFT JOIN? You could have tried copy and pasting this code to your fiddle. Anyway.

Comment: i need a `rank`, you just omitted that completely.

Comment: @sdjkhduiueeuzie, you could simply put a row_numer() there. It is not rank really, anyway I will edit to put it for you. It doesn't really change anything in the answer.